# Help with Ubuntu redirecting Joomla

Tags: apache2

I am fairly lost. I am trying to get up to the "trained monkey" level of knowledge, so please be simple in your answers, and don't assume I know anything. :-)

Environment: Ubuntu 17.1, Apache2, PHP 7.0.

I have two Joomla websites using sh404SEF extension to redirect Joomla URLs like "index.php?option=com_content&Itemid=101&catid=15&id=54&lang=en&view=article" to "/blog/article-name".

They work fine on my hosting, just not on my personal server where I try modifications offline.

I have tried everything I can find here and on other websites. I went into etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf and modified the code thusly:

```
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All (I also tried the suggested AllowOverride FileInfo)
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

My (stripped down) .htaccess file is:

```
    ########## Begin - No directory listings
    ## Note: +FollowSymlinks may cause problems and you might have to remove it
    IndexIgnore *
    # Options +FollowSymLinks All -Indexes
    ########## End - No directory listings## No directory listings

    ########## Begin - File execution order, by Komra.de
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    ########## End - File execution order

    ########## Begin - Activate RewriteBase
    RewriteBase /
    ########## End - Activate RewriteBase

    ## Mod_rewrite in use.

    RewriteEngine On

    ## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
    #
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    #
    # If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
    # has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
    # and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
    #
    ## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

My question is: What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Silly question, but have you installed and enabled Apache rewrite?

Comment: Yes, that was the first step that I did.